# Extract a substring from a Chinese string variable

Tags: unicode, strings, xecjk, chinese

Looks like the `stringstrings` package can do this:

`\substring{This is a string.}{1}{4}`

gives `This`, but it seems to be failed for non-ASCII characters:

`\substring{这是一个句子。}{1}{4}`

cannot give `这是一个`.

Is there a similar package working for Chinese characters？

Comment: Please tell us which TeX engine (pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, something else?) you employ and which language-related packages (if any) you load.

Comment: `XeLaTeX`, with `xecjk`, `xunicode`, `fontspec` packages used, thanks.

Comment: I think that this happens because there are no spaces between chinese characters. So the command works like the whole string is a word.

Comment: @giusva - More likely, it's because (a) in the utf8 encoding system, Chinese characters take up more than 2 bytes and (b) the `stringstrings` package is not sufficiently utf8-aware. (The package's user guide says that it can handle some 2-byte-encoded characters; however, that's not full utf8-awareness.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can switch to LuaLaTeX, it's straightforward to create a "wrapper" LaTeX macro that invokes the Lua function `unicode.utf8.sub`. (`unicode.utf8.sub` is a utf8-aware version of the standard `string.sub` function.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{MingLiU} % or whatever font you prefer
\newcommand\substring[3]{\directlua{%
   tex.sprint( unicode.utf8.sub ( "#1", #2 , #3 ) ) }}
\begin{document}
这是一个句子。

\substring{这是一个句子。}{1}{4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but my case is highly dependent on the `xecjk` package, which does not work with `LuaLaTeX`. If there were no other solutions using `XeLaTeX` in the near future, I think I should mark your answer as accepted.